# How to order grouped results by last id using Eloquent and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, sql-order-by, eloquent

I tried this query but it only order `id` column, rest is not.

```
$chapters = Test::select(DB::raw('*, max(id) as id'))
        ->groupBy('id_equip')
        ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Can you add some example results on your question?

Comment: I assume MySQL. Do you know how `order by` works with `group by` in MySQL? well.. it doesn't.

Comment: this is not a laravel question, this is mysql question,

Comment: @SetKyarWaLar This is a example, but it only order `id` column, you can create `name` to see it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549345/laravel-eloquent-query-group-by-last-id

Comment: @PhucLe It doesn't order anything, that's MySQL.. It just returns `max(id)` per `id_equip`, since this is how aggregates work with group by.

Comment: your query is wrong from init.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk thank you, but how can I group my records by latest id, not first id.

Comment: Please show us the result you're getting (and the one you would like to get)

Comment: @PhucLe OK, here it goes..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In **MySQL** when using `group by` you can't rely on `order by` clause (it won't work as you expect, ie. it will **not** order the results in groups, but rather return *random* row from the group).

So in order to achieve what you want, you need a `subquery` or `join`:

```
// assuming tests table, group by id_equip, order by id
SELECT * FROM tests WHERE id = (
   SELECT MAX(id) FROM tests as t WHERE t.id_equip = tests.id_equip
) ORDER BY id

SELECT * FROM tests 
   JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) as id FROM tests ORDER BY id DESC) as sub
      ON sub.id = tests.id
```

This will get the highest `id` for each `id_equip` and return whole row for each of them.

---

#### Now, in eloquent I suggest first approach, if you want it to look more intuitive:

```
Test::where('id', function ($sub) {
   // subquery
   $sub->selectRaw('max(id)')
       ->from('tests as t')
       ->where('t.id_equip', DB::raw('tests.id_equip'));
// order by
})->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

#### but 2nd appreach is probably the way if you have big table to scan (in terms of performance):

```
Test::join( DB::raw(
    '(select max(id) as id from tests group by id_equip order by id desc) sub'
  ), 'sub.id', '=', 'posts.id')
  ->get(['tests.*']);
```

Here you need to set `order by` clause inside the raw join statement.

You could also build that join subquery with the builder if you like:

```
$sub = Test::selectRaw('max(id)')
        ->groupBy('id_equip')
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->toSql();

Test::join( DB::raw(
    "({$sub}) as sub"
  ), 'sub.id', '=', 'posts.id')
  ->get(['tests.*']);
```